# how to get device IP in WP 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I just need to get the current IP of the device within the local network.
Something like...

```
var IP = IPInformation.GetIP();
```

Sorry for this easy question... just can't find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `GetHostNames()` method through `NetworkInformation` class (`Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation`).

You will retrieve an HostName objects Collection which contain all IP addresses (in `DisplayName` property)

```
List<string> ipAddresses = new List<string>();
var hostnames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
foreach (var hn in hostnames)
       {
         //IanaInterfaceType == 71 => Wifi
         //IanaInterfaceType == 6 => Ethernet (Emulator)
         if (hn.IPInformation != null && 
            (hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 71 
            || hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType == 6))
               {
                  string ipAddress = hn.DisplayName;
                  ipAddresses.Add(ipAddress);
               }
        }
```

[Source](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_get_the_device_IP_addresses_on_Windows_Phone#Getting_IP_Addresses)

Answer (score 1):

The IPAddresses method obtains the selected server IP address information.
It then displays the type of address family supported by the server and its 
IP address in standard and byte format.

```
 private static void IPAddresses(string server) 
    {
      try 
      {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ASCII = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        // Get server related information.
        IPHostEntry heserver = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);

        // Loop on the AddressList 
        foreach (IPAddress curAdd in heserver.AddressList) 
        {


          // Display the type of address family supported by the server. If the 
          // server is IPv6-enabled this value is: InternNetworkV6. If the server 
          // is also IPv4-enabled there will be an additional value of InterNetwork.
          Console.WriteLine("AddressFamily: " + curAdd.AddressFamily.ToString());

          // Display the ScopeId property in case of IPV6 addresses. 
          if(curAdd.AddressFamily.ToString() == ProtocolFamily.InterNetworkV6.ToString())
            Console.WriteLine("Scope Id: " + curAdd.ScopeId.ToString());


          // Display the server IP address in the standard format. In  
          // IPv4 the format will be dotted-quad notation, in IPv6 it will be 
          // in in colon-hexadecimal notation.
          Console.WriteLine("Address: " + curAdd.ToString());

          // Display the server IP address in byte format.
          Console.Write("AddressBytes: ");



          Byte[] bytes = curAdd.GetAddressBytes();
          for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) 
          {
            Console.Write(bytes[i]);
          }                          

          Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

        }
  }
```